# Efficient irregular bitmap hit area

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a Flash project that must display a large amount of irregularly shaped bitmaps (around 10000) and I want to know what bitmap the mouse is currently over. If the mouse is over a transparent part of the bitmap, it shouldn't count as mouse over.

One way to do this is to calculate the hit area, then replace each bitmap with a `Sprite` containing the bitmap and another `Sprite` with the calculated hit area, then set the `hitArea` property. But this is highly inefficient and the result is completely unusable.

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this on the container:

```
var hits:Array = getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(mouseX, mouseY));
if(hits.length > 0)
{
    var bitmap:Bitmap = hits[0] as Bitmap;
    var color:uint = bitmap.bitmapData.getPixel32(bitmap.mouseX, bitmap.mouseY);
    if(color >>> 24 > 0)
    {
        trace('hit: '+bitmap);
    }
}
```

If the Bitmaps overlap, iterate over `hits`.  You can also set a threshold for the transparency.

Comment: To clarify the method in this answer, he's checking if the pixel under the mouse is transparent, and only reporting a hit if it isn't. And note that he first does a normal hitTest to determine which bitmap needs this more detailed check.

Comment: I think my answer is more efficient (unsure) but this method is way simpler and so I would try this first.

Comment: I don't think this answer is inefficient, the getObjectsUnderPoint could still reference a spatial grid

Answer (score 2):

Check [this transparent PNG example out](http://blog.psyrendust.com/2009/02/02/interactivepng-as3-class-to-handle-hit-areas-for-transparent-pngs/), I think it may be just what you're looking for.

[Here is a link to the demo.](http://www.mosessupposes.com/utilities/InteractivePNG_demo.html)

Best of luck.

Comment: This works by handling mouse_over events on the bitmap itself. I need a way that works just by knowing the X and Y position of the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

What I would propose is to make use of something like a [spatial hashing](http://conkerjo.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/spatial-hashing-implementation-for-fast-2d-collisions/). Assuming each bitmap is of a similar size then we can divide your stage into a giant grid, where each cell will be bigger than any given bitmap.

Each bucket in the grid would hold a reference to a bitmap (note that a bitmap might be in more than one cell at a time). When the stage is clicked on, you can retrieve the mouse coordinates to use as a look up into this grid. Then you can iterate through the cell for bitmaps that it contains and check if the x,y coordinates are in the bounding box of the bitmap. If it is, then you can examine the pixel of the bitmap to check if it is a transparent pixel or not.

Assuming a bitmap is found, then you can return it as the bitmap clicked on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have code for this off the top of my head, but what you could do is have a layer for each bitmap where you've filled in the image with a flat color, with a different color for each image. Then on mouse click do a screenshot of the flat color layers and check the color of the pixel under the mouse.

ADDITION: Just saw your comment that the bitmaps don't move. That means you don't need to take a screenshot on mouse click; just take the screenshot once when the bitmaps are first loaded.

Comment: Very good answer. My 2 cents: To do this efficiently, use copyChannel() to copy the alpha channel for each image into new bitmap, then use colorTransform() to give the bitmap a specific color (which is its number out of 10000). Blit these to an off-screen bitmap which is the same size as the display using copyPixels(). When you want to know which sprite the mouse is over, read the pixel using getPixel() at the current mouse coordinates - the color of the pixel will be the number of the sprite. I would post code but this isn't my answer =)

Comment: I think this would be pretty inefficient if I need to check this when the mouse is moved, as opposed to when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If the bitmaps are display objects, use the DisplayObjectContainer method: getObjectsUnderPoint(). This handles irregular vector objects correctly, but I haven't tried with bitmap objects.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work. It doesn't handle transparent pixels differently than opaque ones.

Comment: SO then you move on to checking the pixel in the bitmap under the mouse in the greatly reduced set of bitmap objects returned by getOpjectsUnderPoint(). (This is the same as Sean Fujiwara's answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The big issue is the massive amount of image to loop trough and check for transparency. 
If the bitmaps and their location doesn't change much (relative to each other) then there is a quite clean solution:

```
Make an array of bitmaps(references to bitmaps actually so not consuming a 
gigamount of memory) the size of your screen (or even bigger when you want
to be able to pan around in a bigger area like in a platform game for example).

Loop over all images in z order (beginning with the image furthest away)
  [Calculate a mask for each image (making a black and white bitmap, white is transparent, black is everything else)]
  Loop over the pixels in the image [mask] and update the array (mind the offset) to the current bitmap if not transparent
```

Now each time you want to get the image the mouse is over, you can use this array to look it up.

You'll have to recalculate this every time the layout changes.

This gives you some broad guidelines, there are many possible optimizations possible.